# IOS Crosshatched image: Animate the lines being drawn

Tags: ios, animation, image-processing, ios-animations

I am using the GPUImage2 library on IOS to create filters for my images.

I filter my image with a crosshatch filter, and get something like this:
[image]

I want to animate these black lines falling onto the page, one after the other (kind of like how snapchat animates a mesh onto your face before putting filters on)

I'm not sure if this is possible... Maybe there is a library that can do what I want?

Thanks for the help.